# Problem with Flutter and Firestore, program tries to process data which was not retrieved yet

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Program tries to process data which was not retrieved yet.
I put plenty of displays to verify that this indeed happens.

This my code inside Stateless widget:
....

```
Print(“before calling getDocs()”)
getDocs(); // retrieves data from Firestore
Print(“after calling getDocs()”)
```

data retrieved by getDocs() function is processed
....

getDocs() is defined outside any class or Widget

```
void getDocs() async {
    print("******inside getDocs() start*****************");
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Spanish').get().then((snapshot) {
         print("********inside getDocs() 1"); 
....
    print("******inside getDocs() end*****************");
```

And this is what I see on the log:

```
before calling getDocs()
******inside getDocs() start*****************
******inside getDocs() end*****************
after calling getDocs()
********inside getDocs() 1
```

The result is an error - program tries to process data which was not retrieved yet.
The other display from getDocs() shows the data was received correctly.
Question - how to prevent program to process data when the data is not available yet?

Answer (score 0):

Since `getDocs` is declared as an `async` function, you need to call it with `await` if you want to wait until it's done before continuing processing:

So:

```
await getDocs();
```

If you're in a context where you can't use `await`, you can attach a `then` handler instead:

```
getDocs().then(() {
  ... do whatever needs to happen after getDocs() is done here
})
```